# datetime parse issue c#

Tags: c#

datetime parse work exactly when date format is like mm/dd/yyyy but when dateformat is like dd/mm/yyyy then problem occur. i want to write code to parse date whatever format is used.

suppose if my date is like "15/01/2012" or 05/12/2012 then my code can parse it as valid datetime. so what should i do... i use code like

```
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
string xxx = DateTime.ParseExact("15/12/2012", "yyyyMMdd", culture).ToString();
```

it does not work because dateformat is dd/mm/yyyy. so tell me the best solution that when date format would be dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy etc but code can parse it properly. so guide me what code i should use. thanks

Comment: If the format varies between mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy without indication which is used, you have a problem. For example, what day would 1/2/1996 be? You need more info to be able to select the right one, the computer is an even worse guesser than a human :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *must not* allow both MM/dd/yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy formats without any indication of which is used, or you're just crying out for bad data. What would you interpret "06/05/2011" as? May 6th or June 5th?

You should *either* specify the format explicitly *or* you should use whatever the cultural default is (which shouldn't allow both formats) - but to treat "13/12/2011" differently from "11/12/2011" just because the day value *happens* to be 13 is a really bad idea, IMO.

(The reason your sample code doesn't work is that you're explicitly saying you want it parsed as `yyyyMMdd`, which is clearly *not* the format of `"15/12/2012"`. I'm not sure why you'd ever expect that to work.)

Answer (score 4):

There is an overload of ParseExact that accepts multiple datetime formats. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx